# How to sort a dictionary having string as keys and integer as values in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to sort a dictionnary like:

`dic = {"monday": 1, "tuesday": 1, "wednesday": 10, "thursday": 5, "friday": 10, "saturday": 11, "sunday": 11}`

and I'm trying to have:

`dic = {"saturday": 11, "sunday": 11, "friday": 10, "wednesday": 10, "thursday": 5, "monday": 1, "tuesday": 1}`

So I tried this:

`sortedPairs = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)`

and it seems to be working but for some reasons it never sorts the two lasts and I keep having this:

`{"saturday": 11, "sunday": 11, "friday": 10, "wednesday": 10, "thursday": 5, "tuesday": 1, "monday": 1}`

If someone could please help me out It'd be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. You can try `key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])` without `reverse=True`. What's important to note is that one element is being sorted in ascending order, while the other is being sorted in descending order (the latter takes priority in the tuple sort).

Answer (score 1):

You need to flip the sort order on the day. Since you can't use `-` to compare strings, you should remove `reverse=True` and add `-x[1]`.

```
sortedPairs = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

which is now

```
[('saturday', 11), ('sunday', 11), ('friday', 10), ('wednesday', 10), ('thursday', 5),
 ('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 1)]
```

If you want a dict back use `dict`, but it will only be kept sorted on Python >= 3.7.

```
print(dict(sortedPairs))
# {'saturday': 11, 'sunday': 11, 'friday': 10, 'wednesday': 10, 'thursday': 5, 
#  'monday': 1, 'tuesday': 1}
```